# How to get list of users in MongoDB who have at least N unready messages?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Node.js and MongoDB (Mongoose.js) in my project. I have some sort of messaging system in it. Collection that stores messages has next schema:

```
{
  message: "Some message text",
  user: "54835b0c3d36170c0c6da7f5",
  read: 0
}
```

`user` — is id of user whom this message addressed to. `read` field has two possible values: `0` — user didn't read message yet, `1` — already read message.

The problem is to get list of user ids who have 5 and more unread messages. The most obvious solution is to get list of all unread messages, iterate through it and build list of user based on it. But this looks not as best solution (in terms of performance).

I think there should be a better way to get this done. Probably by using aggregation framework.

I would appreciate for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "read": 0 }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user",
            "unread_count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }        
    },
    {
        "$match": { 
            "unread_count": { "$gte": 5 }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: easy and simple, my `$cond` was too much :)

Comment: What's the difference between using aggregation and performing a query with the `$gte` operator?

Comment: @diegoaguilar Performing a query with the `$gte` operator would need a field that would hold the number of unread messages and the current schema doesn't have that, that's why you would need aggregation to get the count.

Comment: @chridam will this solution work if `user` field is `ObjectId` instance, not a string? I provided a bit wrong schema. In my particular case `user` is `ObjectId` instance. I executed your code and it didn't return any results (there is for sure enough of unread messages for at least one user).

Comment: @chridam sorry, I've made a mistake when tested your code. It works perfect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, using the aggregation framework :) like this:

```
db.messages.aggregate([
                         {
                            $group: {
                                       _id: "$user",
                                       unread_messages: {$sum: {$cond: ["$read", 0, 1]}}
                                    },
                         },
                         {
                            $match: {
                                       unread_messages: {$gte: 5}
                                    }
                         }
                      ])
```

The point here is that we `$group` all the messages of each user, and add `1` to unread messages count if the `read` field is `0`.

Then you just `$match` the documents that have the new `unread_messages` greater than or equal to `5`.